# delete activity_main (small/xLarge/large) in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have created  small size screen file for activity_main, and now I want to delete it. When I try to delete activity_main (small). all files of activity_main are deleted.

activity_main

activity_main (small) <----

activity_main (normal)

activity_main (xlarge)

How can I delete only small activity_main ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Change project structure from "Android" to "Project".
   [see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXPDl.png)
2. Navigate to "res" folder then "layout-small" and delete the file.

Comment: Thanks A lot <3<3<3

Answer (score 0):

-you can follow this step

1) open project in android studio

2) open res/layout folder

3) select file want to delete

[image]

4) delete file, one popup display in that uncheck safe delete press ok.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

OR
Manually delete the file from its location.Then sync the project.(sync button - Third button in the Main toolBar)

[image]